# my program prints some arbit ascii string

Tags: c

I wrote following program

```
int main ()
{
char a=0xf;
a=a+1;
printf("%c\n",a);
}
```

the output of above program is what I am not able to understand.It is giving me some character which I am not able to understand.Is it possible to find out ASCII code of the character that I am getting in my above program so that I understand what is it printing.

**EDIT**

Based on the replies I read I am adding further to my confusion

if I write a statement as following

char ch='Z';

then what would be stored in ch,

1) The character Z
2) ASCII value of Z
3) Z along with single inverted commas
4) Both (1) and (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters from 0 to 31 are non-printing characters (in your case, you've chosen 0xF, which is 15 in decimal).  Many of the obscure ones were designed for [teletypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASR-33_Teletype) and other ancient equipment.  Try a character from 32 to 126 instead.  See http://www.asciitable.com for details.

In response to your second question, the character stores the decimal value 90 (as characters are really 1-byte integers).  `'Z'` is just notation that `Z` is meant to be taken as a character and not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

ASCII value for 16(0x0f + 1 = 0x10) is `DLE (data link escape)` which is non-printable character.
Just Print as integer like this.

```
printf("%d\n",a);
```

Comment: I want to know how did you come to that statement 16(0x0f+1)

Comment: @Registered User: `0x0f` is 15 in decimal and adding one to it is 16 0r 0x10 in hex. 0x means hex

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your program like that:

```
int main ()
{
  char a=0xf;
  a=a+1;
  printf("Decimal:%u Hexa:%x Actual Char:|%c|\n",a,a,a);
}
```

Printf can use different formatting for a character.

Comment: I read your thing I am new comer to C hence trying to understand it if a=0xf then how will a=a+1 work ?

Comment: it will add 1 to a. a current value is 0xf in hexa, meaning 15 in decimal or 01111 in binary form. When adding 1, new value will be (provided there is no overflow, like now)  16=0x10=0b10000. It will try to print the ascii character corresponding to that (you can check an ascii table then)

Comment: @Registered `char`s are 1-byte integers, you can perform arithmetic on them

Comment: @Registered Yes, they store the ASCII code for the character.  Character is usually a signed value, so you can store numbers ranging from -128 to 127 in those 8 bits.  If you cast your char to an integer you can see the ASCII value. `char a = 'Z'; int i; i = (int)a;`

Answer (score 0):

Its printing the character 0x10 (16).

If you want the output, change your print to output the values (in this case, character, hex value, decimal value):

`printf("%c - %x - %d\n", a, a, a);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()    
{

    char a='z';                 \\\ascii value of z is stored in a i.e 122

    a=a+1;   \\\a now becomes 123

    printf("%c",a);   \\\ 123 corresponds to character '{' 

}
```